# MySQL retornando null indevidamente - MYSQLI PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando efetuar um SELECT através do mysqli do PHP, porém ele está retornando *null* em todos os parâmetros do objeto retornado pelo *$mysqli->query($sql)*.

[image: O objeto que retornou após o método query]

Mesmo assim ele retorna as linhas que selecionei da tabela, só que alguns valores tem vindo *null* também:

[image: Linha retornada pelo SELECT]

Segue meu código:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cell_number = $_POST['cell'];

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM SMS WHERE Number LIKE '%%%s%%'", $cell_number);
$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);


while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

die(json_encode(array('resultado' => $result, 'debug' => $query, 'sql' => $sql)));
```

Já tentei ver se poderia ser algum erro de sintaxe do MySQL, mas joguei a query diretamente no banco e funcionou normalmente. Tive o mesmo problema com outro código que estava fazendo ontem e não consegui resolver. É estranho, levando em consideração que sempre faço da mesma forma e funciona...

Onde estou errando? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigada.

Comment: Sim, retorno em formato JSON para usar no Ajax.

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo, Guilherme. Estou trazendo o resultado em array de PHP ao invés de JSON e está retornando certo. Você sabe porque isso pode estar acontecendo? Sempre usei muito a conversão de arrays para JSON e nunca tive esse problema.

Comment: Editado. Coloquei os dois últimos índices apenas para fim de debug.

Comment: Só uma duvida, na tabela os campos `EmailCounterpart`, `Provider`, `Balance` e `Direction` estão em branco?

Comment: O `EmailCounterpart`, `Provider` e `Direction` normalmente vem em branco mesmo. Mas o `Balance` e o `Message` que estão vindo nulos no JSON sempre vem preenchidos.

Comment: Guilherme, agradeço sua ajuda. Como nosso colega Bruno disse em baixo, o problema era que eu estava enviando um dado que não está em UTF-8 para o json_encode, por isso não estava funcionando. Consegui resolver :)

Comment: Que bom, lhe desejo sucesso no seu projeto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mais uma vez os grandes vilões da história são o *charset* e o "achismo" do PHP.

[json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) aceita strings apenas quando codificadas em UTF-8. Caso encontre alguma durante o processo de codificação, o PHP vai assumir aquele valor como NULL, quietinho, ao invés de te dar um toque com algum Notice, por exemplo.

Você pode corrigir isso alterando a codificação dos seus dados antes de informar o array para [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode). Duas maneiras fáceis de se conseguir isso é com a [iconv](http://php.net/iconv) ou [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding).

Por exemplo, assumindo que suas informações no banco estejam armazenadas com *charset* **latin1**, você faria isso:

```
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {

    $result[] = array_map(

        function( $string ) {

            return iconv( 'iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', $string );

        }, $row
    );
}
```

Aqui foi usada uma função anônima nos moldes de uma Closure, disponível a partir do PHP 5.3. Eu espero que você esteja usando pelo menos essa versão, mas em todo o caso você pode fazer:

```
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {

    $result[] = array_map( 'cb', $row );
}

// ...

function cb( $string ) {
    return iconv( "iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $string );
}
```

A alternativa mais trabalhosa, porém mais adequada, seria criar um novo banco de dados, já em UTF-8 e re-inserir todos os dados também em UTF-8.

Claro que você não precisaria fazer manualmente, poderia criar um script que fizesse por você, mas isso são outros quinhentos.

Adaptado [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345680/753531) no SOEn.

Comment: Muito obrigada, Bruno! Não fiz exatamente igual. Meu banco está em UTF-8, mas as strings que eu estava mandando não. fiz um `array_map('utf8_encode', $row)` antes de dar o json_encode e funcionou!

Comment: Também serve. Não mencionei porque depender de utf8_encode() sempre me cheirou a gambiarra.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar fazer do jeito que você mostrou acima. Ontem não consegui, mas vou dar uma fuçada melhor. Valeu.

Comment: É basicamente a mesma coisa que você conseguiu fazer, só que caso o servidor tenha sido configurado por chimpanzé, a ICONV pode ter sido manualmente desabilitada. Já as funções *multibyte* (mb_*) requerem uma biblioteca externa que talvez não esteja habilitada no servidor.